# using subclipse extension points to connect to svn repo from custom plugin

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I am working on creating Eclipse plugin which in turn requires to connect to svn repository.

I see that eclipse subversion plugin has the svnkit extension point[image: SVNkit plugin screenshot]

I am looking to use this extension point to connect to svn repository. But as per description it mentions "This extension point allows additional SVNConnectorFactory to be pluged in.  It is for internal use."

Can someone point me in right direction of usage?

Do I need to use separate library(maybe SVNKit) to connect to svn from my custom plugin?

Comment: I've used [`SVNKit` API](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/) to connect to a `svn` repo, but not from an eclipse plugin. I don't think it makes any difference, though - you should be able to do what you want to do with the `svn` repo using the `SVNKit` API. I haven't tried connecting to the `subclipse` extension point since I didn't need the feature on an eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an Extension Point.  You should require the Subclipse core plugin and do something like this in your code so that you get an ISVNClientAdapter.

```
ISVNClientAdapter client = null;
try {
    client = SVNProviderPlugin.getPlugin().getSVNClientManager().getSVNClient();
    // Now do whatever you need to do
    client.XXX;
} catch (Exception e) {}
finally {
    SVNProviderPlugin.getPlugin().getSVNClientManager().returnSVNClient(client);
}
```